# php 2 page form validation with css

Tags: php, validation

I am trying to use php for my form validation for the first time. I get how to build my errors array and display it. Can anyone explain a technique that I could use to color the field with the error in the form? Dont even know where to start to attempt this. My forms are processed on a separate page.

Comment: That's typically done on the client side with Javascript and CSS

Comment: Yeah, Paul is right. Javascript is normally used for client side validation, php for secure additional server validation validation. (You can have a look at very good [Javascript Form Validator](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml)) Ajax is good to make user friendly form fields, but only rarely it is used for form validation (like registration of new unique username).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a multidimensional array:

```
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$error[0] = array("Your password must be 8-20 characters in length", "red")
if(str_len($pass) > 20 || str_len($pass) < 8){
    $finalError = $error[0];
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<input style="background-color:<?echo $finalError[1]?>" name="pass"/>
```

This is assuming you aren't using ajax to validate...

Comment: Havent tested yet but this looks like it will work. Would ajax be a better way to validate my forms?

Comment: definietly not as your sole validator.  if you are going for a secure solution, you will need to validate without ajax at some point or the user can just modify the page using the developer panel after you validate using ajax. if you would like though, you can use ajax as well as what you're currently using so the user gets immediate feedback as they are typing rather than waiting for the page to reload after they submit the form.

Comment: ok sounds like thats what I need. ajax for the visuals and php for the real deal validation. thanks!